# No dispaly on BBB running with android marshmallow

Tags: android, android-source, beagleboneblack

I have started to compile aosp for BBB using the link https://github.com/csimmonds/android4beagle/tree/master to compile android-6.0 for BeagleBoneBlack. I proceeded with **beagleboneblack_sd-eng.** and got a successful build, using the boot button I manged to run the android image via SD card on BBB but their is no display at all, attached a screenshot to prove that its running on android. I have a cape connected to BBB but its blank. To dig deeper I connected the FTDI cable on BBB serial port and found that BBB is running fine with that image.
[image]
I have some experience in embedded linux not in android linux. Can anybody please help me out and explain what's going on here?

Comment: Can you please clarify if you checked the HDMI output and what sort of display cape you have?

Comment: Nothing comes up on HDMI output as well. This is the cape which I am using https://www.4dsystems.com.au/product/4DCAPE_70T/

Answer (score 0):

OK, so there are two things:

- make sure that the Linux Kernel you use has support for the display used in that cape
- make sure that the kernel knows about the display: Put it in the device tree that U-Boot hands to the kernel on boot.

You're lucky in the sense that this seems to be compatible with the original CCo LCD7 cape. You should still make sure that the TI 4.1 kernel actually supports it.

I'm not sure which part builds the DTB, so you'll have to look into the build script and trace that back. It should be close to or part of the kernel build.

Another tip: Try bringing up the display on a regular up to date debian image first. That should help you understand how things fit together and what needs to be added to the DT. Those also offer multiple kernels, so you can try some out.